# Redirect Environment variables in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have three variables lets say SOURCE_SUCCESS, JULIANDAYS, APPROVEREJECT

Value of SOURCE_SUCCESS=**a,b,c,d,e,f**

Value of JULIANDAYS=**1,2,3,4,5**

Value Of APPROVEREJECT=**A,R,A,A,R**

Now what i want to do it here is to print the values of the three variables in the format as shown below using batch file commands

a          1           A
b          2           R

and so on

One more point i want to redirect this to a file

Answer (score 1):

This DOS-based approach works for your specific request:

```
@echo off
set SOURCE_SUCCESS=a,b,c,d,e,f
set JULIANDAYS=1,2,3,4,5
set APPROVEREJECT=A,R,A,A,R 

:ROW1
for /f "tokens=1" %%j in ('echo %SOURCE_SUCCESS%') do set col1=%%j
for /f "tokens=1" %%j in ('echo %JULIANDAYS%') do set col2=%%j
for /f "tokens=1" %%j in ('echo %APPROVEREJECT%') do set col3=%%j
echo %col1%  %col2%  %col3% > myfile.txt

:ROW2
for /f "tokens=2" %%j in ('echo %SOURCE_SUCCESS%') do set col1=%%j
for /f "tokens=2" %%j in ('echo %JULIANDAYS%') do set col2=%%j
for /f "tokens=2" %%j in ('echo %APPROVEREJECT%') do set col3=%%j
echo %col1%  %col2%  %col3% >> myfile.txt

:ROW3
for /f "tokens=3" %%j in ('echo %SOURCE_SUCCESS%') do set col1=%%j
for /f "tokens=3" %%j in ('echo %JULIANDAYS%') do set col2=%%j
for /f "tokens=3" %%j in ('echo %APPROVEREJECT%') do set col3=%%j
echo %col1%  %col2%  %col3% >> myfile.txt

:ROW4
for /f "tokens=4" %%j in ('echo %SOURCE_SUCCESS%') do set col1=%%j
for /f "tokens=4" %%j in ('echo %JULIANDAYS%') do set col2=%%j
for /f "tokens=4" %%j in ('echo %APPROVEREJECT%') do set col3=%%j
echo %col1%  %col2%  %col3% >> myfile.txt

:ROW5
for /f "tokens=5" %%j in ('echo %SOURCE_SUCCESS%') do set col1=%%j
for /f "tokens=5" %%j in ('echo %JULIANDAYS%') do set col2=%%j
for /f "tokens=5" %%j in ('echo %APPROVEREJECT%') do set col3=%%j
echo %col1%  %col2%  %col3% >> myfile.txt
```

Output:

```
a  1  A
b  2  R
c  3  A
d  4  A
e  5  R
```

I had also tried the following to be more flexible in case you ever have a variable number of tokens, but it appears DOS rejects variables in the token specifier (whether using delayed variable expansion or not).  Maybe someone else knows why?:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set SOURCE_SUCCESS=a,b,c,d,e,f
set JULIANDAYS=1,2,3,4,5
set APPROVEREJECT=A,R,A,A,R 

REM The following doesn't work because variable as 'tokens' are rejected
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) Do (
   set fieldnum=%%i
   for /f "tokens=!fieldnum!" %%j in ('echo %SOURCE_SUCCESS%') do echo %%j
   for /f "tokens=!fieldnum!" %%k in ('echo %JULIANDAYS%') do echo %%k
   for /f "tokens=!fieldnum!" %%l in ('echo %APPROVEREJECT%') do echo %%l
)
```

Comment: Options of _nested_ `FOR /F` commands can not include a parameter of the nesting/parent `FOR`. It may, however, include a Batch file parameter, so you may extract the three FOR's and place them into a subroutine. However, this solution does NOT show the three values _in the same line_ as requested.

Comment: Aacini, you are correct that my non-working version wouldn't output them on the same line even if it did work. Setting (vs. echoing) the %%i, %%j, and %%k in the "FOR /F" lines was the concept I had started to attempt before realizing the overall approach didn't work, after which I just hacked up my notes using echos.

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below work with any number of tokens/fields:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set SOURCE_SUCCESS=a,b,c,d,e,f
set JULIANDAYS=1,2,3,4,5
set APPROVEREJECT=A,R,A,A,R 
set i=0
for %%a in (%SOURCE_SUCCESS%) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set result[!i!]=%%a
)
set /A n=i, i=0
for %%a in (%JULIANDAYS%) do (
    set /A i+=1
    for %%i in (!i!) do set result[%%i]=!result[%%i]! %%a
)
if %i% gtr %n% set n=%i%
set i=0
for %%a in (%APPROVEREJECT%) do (
    set /A i+=1
    for %%i in (!i!) do set result[%%i]=!result[%%i]! %%a
)
if %i% gtr %n% set n=%i%
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !result[%%i]! >> thefile.txt
```

This is the result:

```
a 1 A
b 2 R
c 3 A
d 4 A
e 5 R
f
```

**EDIT**: *New method added*

The Batch file below is smaller and allows an easier processing of any number of variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set SOURCE_SUCCESS=a,b,c,d,e,f
set JULIANDAYS=1,2,3,4,5
set APPROVEREJECT=A,R,A,A,R 
set n=0
for %%v in (SOURCE_SUCCESS JULIANDAYS APPROVEREJECT) do (
    set i=0
    for %%a in (!%%v!) do (
        set /A i+=1
        for %%i in (!i!) do set result[%%i]=!result[%%i]! %%a
    )
    if !i! gtr !n! set n=!i!
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !result[%%i]! >> thefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ paste <(echo $SOURCE_SUCCESS | tr ',' '\n') <(echo $JULIANDAYS | tr ',' '\n') <(echo $APPROVEREJECT | tr ',' '\n') >output.txt

$ cat output.txt
a       1       A
b       2       R
c       3       A
d       4       A
e       5       R
f
```

**Note:** It would be easier if you put all values line by line into separated files.

Comment: Want this in windows batch scripting

Comment: You can install `GNU-utils` for windows.

Comment: On a related note, it baffles me that Windows has a `clip` program, but not a "`paste`" or `clip /p` . I found that using getclip/putclip changes the line endings.